# Ocaml Print List of Tuples

Tags: ocaml

I would like to print a list of tuples of type `(int * 'a) list`. For example for printing this list of tuples

```
[(3, "toto");(1, "a")]
```

or this list

```
[(3, 4);(1, 7)]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in support for printing lists, tuples, or a type of any kind more generally. You have to be specific, and since a list can contain any type and a tuple can be a product of any types you have deconstruct it yourself and format it appropriately.

Here's an example of a function which iterates through the list, deconstructs each tuple, and formats them with a comma separating the items of the tuple and a semicolon separating the tuples themselves:

```
let rec print_tuples =
  function
  | [] -> ()
  | (a, b) :: rest ->
    Printf.printf "%i, %s; " a b;
    print_tuples rest

let () =
  print_tuples [(3, "toto");(1, "a")]
```

[The documentation for Printf](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) lists which other types you can print in this way, and the placeholders to use.

Comment: Also Using `List.iter` : `let print_ltuples l = List.iter (fun (a,b) -> Printf.printf "%d, %s " a b);`

Answer (score 3):

With `Fmt` (which is an improved api over Format) printing a list of tuple can be done by first defining a printer for a pair of `int` and `string` separated by a `comma`:

```
let pair_printer = Fmt.(pair ~sep:comma int string)
```

For the next step, we can define a printer for a list of those `int * string` tuples, separated by a semi-colon:

```
let list_printer = Fmt.(list ~sep:(const pf ";@ ") pair_printer)
```

And then finally, we can use this printer with:

```
Fmt.pr "[%a]@." list_printer [1, "one"; 2, "two" ]
```